# Salary PAYE brackets using a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-insert

I am trying to insert into an `Employee` table and I want the if statements to insert into the `Salary`, `NetSalary`, and `Deduction` columns if the `Employee` will earn a certain amount based on the hourly rate.

If statements are meant to insert data into the relevant column when the amount falls into a particular bracket

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spSaveEmployee]
    (@EmployeePersonName Varchar(20),
     @JobTitle int,
     @Branch int,
     @Department int,
     @Manager int,
     @HourlyRate MONEY,
     @PaymentDate datetime = '2021-10-05 00:00:00.000',
     @ErrorMessage Varchar(50) OUTPUT)
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @DefaultDate DATETIME = GETDATE()

    --DECLARE @PAYE INT 
    --SET @PAYE = 26 / 100

    DECLARE @Salary INT
    --SET @Salary = @HourlyRate * 180
   
    --DECLARE @PYE INT
    --SET @PYE = 1.15
    DECLARE @NetSalary MONEY
    DECLARE @Deduction DECIMAL (18,2)

    DECLARE @NetSalary1 MONEY
    DECLARE @NetSalary2 MONEY
    DECLARE @NetSalary3 MONEY

    --SET @NetSalary = @Salary - @PYE

    DECLARE @Deduction1 DECIMAL (18,2)
    DECLARE @Deduction2 DECIMAL (18,2)
    DECLARE @Deduction3 DECIMAL (18,2)

    SET @Deduction1 = (@Salary * 18) / 100
    SET @NetSalary1 =  @Salary - @Deduction1
  
    SET @Deduction2 = (@Salary * 26) / 100
    SET @NetSalary2 =  @Salary - @Deduction2

    SET @Deduction3 = (@Salary * 31) / 100
    SET @NetSalary3 =  @Salary - @Deduction3

    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM EmployeeBook 
                   WHERE EmployeePersonName = @EmployeePersonName)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO EmployeeBook (EmployeePersonName, JobTitle, Branch, Department, 
                                  Manager, HourlyRate, PAYE_Tax, Salary, 
                                  NetSalary, PaymentDate, Deductions)
        VALUES (@EmployeePersonName, @JobTitle, @Branch, @Department,
                @Manager, @HourlyRate, 1.15, @Salary,
                @NetSalary, @DefaultDate, @Deduction)

        SET @ErrorMessage = ''
        
        IF @Salary <= 321000
        BEGIN
            SELECT @Deduction = @Deduction
            SELECT @NetSalary = @NetSalary
        END 
        ELSE IF @Salary >= 321001 AND @Salary <= 445100
        BEGIN
            SELECT @Deduction = @Deduction2
            SELECT @NetSalary =  @NetSalary2
        END 
        ELSE IF @Salary >= 445100 AND @Salary <= 584200
        BEGIN
            SELECT @Deduction = @Deduction3
            SELECT @NetSalary = @NetSalary3 
        END
    END 
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @EmployeePersonName = '' 
        SET @JobTitle = 0 
        SET @Branch = 0
        SET @Department = 0
        SET @Manager = 0
        SET @HourlyRate = 0.00
        SET @Salary = 0.00
        SET @NetSalary = 0.00
        SET @PaymentDate = @DefaultDate
        SET @Deduction = 0

        SET @ErrorMessage = 'Sorry could not save ' + @EmployeePersonName + ' Employee name already exists'
    END
END
GO
```

Comment: Why `SET` all those variables at the end if you aren't going to use them? Also wouldn't you be better off `THROW`ing the error rather than returning it as an `OUTPUT` parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following does what I believe you are trying to accomplish. Issues and comments:

1. You set your variables after you use them - so they have no effect.
2. T-SQL is optimised for set-based operations therefore you should attempt to carry out your operations in a set-based manner if possible rather than procedural
3. Best practice is to use consistent casing for T-SQL
4. As Larnu points out, error handling is best handled using throw.
5. Best practice is to always schema prefix your database objects
6. SPs should always have a return statement
7. SPs should normally start `SET NOCOUNT, XACT_ABORT ON;`
8. Since you can validate the existence of the person straight away, I would and save any further processing time.
9. What if the salary falls outside the defined brackets? You might not expect it, but you should handle it hence the `ELSE` in the `CASE` expression.
10. I would avoid prefixing your SP's with `sp` as its too close to the system prefix `sp_`. In fact why prefix them at all?
11. When creating brackets like this, one end condition needs to be `less than or equal` and the other condition `greater than` (or vice-versa) to avoid a value falling into 2 brackets. Even though the `case` will short-circuit to the first matching expression, its best from an understanding perspective to have correct and accurate logic.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SaveEmployee]
(
    @EmployeePersonName VARCHAR(20),
    @JobTitle INT,
    @Branch INT,
    @Department INT,
    @Manager INT,
    @HourlyRate MONEY,
    @PaymentDate DATETIME = '2021-10-05 00:00:00.000',
    @ErrorMessage VARCHAR(50) OUTPUT
)
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT, XACT_ABORT ON;

    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.EmployeeBook WHERE EmployeePersonName = @EmployeePersonName) BEGIN
        SET @ErrorMessage = 'Sorry could not save ' + @EmployeePersonName + ' Employee name already exists' END
        RETURN;
        -- Comment out 2 lines above to uncomment the 2 code line below
        -- As suggested by Larnu, this would be more a typical error handling approach
        --DECLARE @Error NVARCHAR(2048) = 'Sorry could not save ' + @EmployeePersonName + ' Employee name already exists';
        --THROW 51000, @Error, 1;
    END;

    DECLARE @DefaultDate DATETIME = GETDATE(), @Salary INT = @HourlyRate * 180;

    INSERT INTO dbo.EmployeeBook (EmployeePersonName, JobTitle, Branch, Department 
        , Manager, HourlyRate, PAYE_Tax, Salary 
        , NetSalary, PaymentDate, Deductions)
    SELECT EmployeePersonName, JobTitle, Branch, Department
        , Manager, HourlyRate, 1.15, Salary
        , CASE SalaryBracket WHEN 1 THEN Salary - Deduction1
          WHEN 2 THEN Salary - Deduction2
          WHEN 3 THEN Salary - Deduction3
          -- ELSE ??
          END
        , @DefaultDate
        , CASE SalaryBracket WHEN 1 THEN Deduction1
          WHEN 2 THEN Deduction2
          WHEN 3 THEN Deduction3
          -- ELSE ??
          END
    FROM (
        VALUES (@EmployeePersonName, @JobTitle, @Branch, @Department, @Manager, @HourlyRate, 1.15, @Salary
          , (@Salary * 18) / 100, (@Salary * 26) / 100, (@Salary * 31) / 100
          -- Compute Salary Bracket in one place for reuse
          , CASE WHEN @Salary <= 321000 THEN 1
            WHEN @Salary > 321001 AND @Salary <= 445100 THEN 2
            WHEN @Salary > 445100 AND @Salary <= 584200 THEN 3 END
          )
    ) AS X (EmployeePersonName, JobTitle, Branch, Department, Manager, HourlyRate, PAYE_Tax, Salary, Deduction1, Deduction2, Deduction3, SalaryBracket);

    RETURN 0;
END
GO
```

Comment: `WHEN @Salary >= 321001 AND @Salary <= 445100 THEN 2` and `WHEN @Salary >= 445100 AND @Salary <= 584200 THEN 2`? Shouldn't the last one return `3`? Although it copies the OP's logic, it probably makes sense to have only one choice apply if `@Salary` is `445100`.

Comment: Thank you @Dale this is such a clear and simple way to do it and it works like a charm